# For each row in one table, find the next row by timestamp with a corresponding uid

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working in SQL, specifically Amazon Redshift.

Suppose I have data on how users navigate a website:

| user_id | timestamp | page_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4:30pm | homepage |
| 3 | 4:32pm | homepage |
| 4 | 4:40pm | profile_page |
| 1 | 4:41pm | profile_page |
| 2 | 4:48pm | homepage |
| 2 | 4:59pm | friends_list |
| 4 | 5:27pm | homepage |
| 3 | 5:29pm | product_page |
| 4 | 5:34pm | product_page |
| 1 | 5:49pm | friends_list |
| 2 | 5:56pm | product_page |
| 2 | 5:59pm | homepage |

I want to see where users navigate next after reaching the homepage. My final output would look something along the lines of

| page_name | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| homepage | 0 |
| profile_page | 1 |
| friends_list | 1 |
| product_page | 2 |

because the next place users 3 and 4 went after visiting the homepage was product_page, the next place user 1 went was profile_page, the next place user 2 went was friends_list, and nobody visited the homepage twice in a row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the process of trying to formulate my question I may have helped myself find an answer, so posting the solution I've found here:
My current best attempt is to use the LEAD() function

```
select next_page, count(next_page) as count
from
(select lead(page_name) as next_page
from table
where page_name = 'homepage'
and user_id = lead(user_id)
order by user_id, timestamp)

group by next_page
```

Suggestions for more optimized approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the next page, you can use `lead()`.  The correct logic is:

```
select next_page_name, count(*) as frequency
from (select t.*,
             lead(page_name) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as next_page_name
      from t
     ) t
where page_name = 'homepage'
group by next_page_name;
```

Note:  This does not return `0` counts.  I'm not sure they are useful.  If you have a list of pages that you care about, you can use a `left join`.  Otherwise, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select next_page_name,
       sum( (page_name = 'homepage')::int ) as frequency
from (select t.*,
             lead(page_name) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as next_page_name
      from t
     ) t
group by next_page_name;
```

This also returns `NULL` if there is no next page.  That does seem useful.